# Most efficient way to erase from a set while iterating over it

Tags: c++

What's the most efficient way to erase from a set while iterating over it? Here are two approaches I've thought of, which is the best between them? Is there another better way?

```
void WaitForFiles(std::set<string> files) {
  while (files.size() > 0) {
    std::set<string> found_files;
    for (const auto& file : files) {
      if (Exists(file)) {
        found_files.insert(file);
      }
    }
    for (const auto& found_file : found_files) {
      files.erase(file);
    }
  }
}
```

Using set_difference:

```
void WaitForFiles(std::set<string> files) {
  while (files.size() > 0) {
    std::set<string> found_files;
    for (const auto& file : files) {
      if (Exists(file)) {
        found_files.insert(file);
      }
    }
    std::set<string> difference;
    std::set_difference(files.begin(), files.end(),
                        found_files.begin(), found_files.end(),
                        std::inserter(difference, difference.end()));
    files = difference;
  }
}
```

Note that the following crashes:

```
void WaitForFiles(std::set<string> files) {
  while (files.size() > 0) {
    for (const auto& file : files) {  // <-- seg fault after first erase
      if (Exists(file)) {
        files.erase(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For determining efficiency, keep in mind that in my case the file may take 30 minutes to come into existence, so the Exists function will get called many times and the files set will not change very often compared to the number of times the loop is iterated over.

Comment: Instead of having `found_files` be a `set`, make it a `vector` instead.

Comment: Instead of using 100% thread time for an indefinite amount of time, you might be better off using some OS facility such as notifications on changes in a folder or alike. Benefit of "going event based" is also that you will always erase a file as soon as it shows up and your "erase while iterating" problem is not even there.

Comment: MarkRansom, How would that improve things?
BitTickler, Unfortunately the file system I am using does not support notifications. Imagine that the file is a 3rd party website.

Comment: Okay but if you loop anyway, why do you ask for efficiency? Why would it matter, if your perma-loop loops once per 500us or once per 1ms?

Comment: Erasing from the set invalidates the hidden iterator that the range-based-for loop is using. Instead you need to write the loop using explicit iterators, and use the new iterator returned by the `erase` method.

Comment: To possibly increase performance, pass `files` by const reference, and make `found_files` store pointers (or iterators) to strings and (if you want to avoid duplicates in the set) use a custom compare function that will dereference the elements before comparing.

Comment: I meant vectors are more efficient than sets, and the way you were using `found_files` there was no advantage to having it be a set. But Chris Drew's answer shows you how to eliminate it entirely, which is 100% better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour to erase from a set within a ranged-based for loop (even if it appears to work). Ranged-based for loops use an iterator internally and erasing the element invalidates the iterator.

But `std::set::erase` returns a valid iterator to the next element in the `std::set` so you can use an explicit iterator loop instead:

```
for(auto itr = files.cbegin(); itr != files.cend();) {
  if (exists(*itr)) {
    std::cout << "Found file: " << *itr << "\n";
    itr = files.erase(itr);
  } else
    ++itr;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PaniSyvoU08TmqcO)

Comment: Side question. Is files.erase(itr) faster than files.erase(*itr)? Or is it implementation defined?

Comment: @AffluentOwl The first is almost certainly going to faster. The second has to find the element in the set,  the first does not.

Comment: @AffluentOwl files.erase(*itr) isn't an option for this; it doesn't return an iterator (and can't, since it may be erasing multiple elements).

Answer (score 4):

With [`std::experimental::erase_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/set/erase_if) from v2 of the library fundamentals TS:

```
std::experimental::erase_if(files, Exists);
```

If `Exists` is overloaded or is a function template, use a lambda:

```
std::experimental::erase_if(files, [](const auto& f) { return Exists(f); });
```

This is already implemented in VS2015.

Comment: I really like this answer because the link explains what erase_if is equivalent to.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two examples look suboptimal because they both involve iterating through the *set* twice. Your third example is unstable because you continue to use the iterator after you invalidate it by changing the set using `std::set::erase`.

I would imagine the following should be reasonably efficient. However as others mentioned it may be worth replacing the `std::set<std::string> found_files` with a `std::vector`.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * Return true for every other call
 */
bool Exists(std::string const&)
{
    static int i = 0;
    return ++i % 2;
}

std::set<std::string> find_existing_files(std::set<std::string>& files)
{
    std::set<std::string> found_files;

    for(auto file = files.begin(); file != files.end();)
    {
        if(!Exists(*file))
            ++file; // not erasing, keep going
        else
        {
            found_files.insert(*file);
            // replacing iterator with result of erase()
            // keeps the iterator valid
            file = files.erase(file);
        }
    }
    return found_files;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> files {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};

    for(auto const& file: find_existing_files(files))
        std::cout << "exists : " << file << '\n';

    for(auto const& file: files)
        std::cout << "missing: " << file << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
exists : a
exists : c
exists : e
missing: b
missing: d
```

Comment: Now you are always returning an empty set :)

Comment: @T.C. Hehe, this is the problem with editing to many things *at the same time*.